# Как установить слушатель на НЕ первый запуск приложения android

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver, статистика

Подскажите, каким образом можно установить слушатель на каждый не первый запуск приложения?

Есть идея писать в файл количество запусков и каждый раз на запуске читать из файла это число, инкрементить и писать обратно. И на основании этого счётчика выполнять проверку. Но это кажется немного топорным вариантом, наверняка система андроид предлагает какие то решения.

Есть ли возможность создать некий `BroadcastReceiver`, который будет слушать все запуски приложения и проверять, какой это запуск по счёту или может быть который будет проверять абсолютно все запуски, а проверку выполнять в коде? Я пока нашел для ресиверов экшны на изменение, удаление, добавление, первый запуск пакета. Но такого, как нужно, мне найти не удалось. Может кто то сталкивался с такой задачей, что можно сделать?

Comment: SharedPreferences наверное

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обычно такие вопросы решаются через `SharedPreferences`, в таком способе нет ничего топорного.
Создаете булево значение и в стартовой активити при запуске пишите туда `true`, потом проверяете, если `true`, значит уже запускалось приложение.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

          //Получаем значение флага. 
          //Если ни разу не запускалось, то такой записи нет
          // значение по дефолту false

    boolean isAgain = sp.getBoolean("isAgain", false);

    if (isAgain) {

        // действия, когда приложение запускалось повторно.

    }

    // Записываем `true` - первый запуск прошел

    Editor e = sp.edit();
    e.putBoolean("isAgain", true);
    e.apply(); 

   // Прочий код

}
```