# Как изменить точку входа в приложение?

Tags: android, activity, android-manifest

Есть приложение, которое при первом запуске загружать некоторые данные. При следующих запусках необходимо, чтобы открывалось не первое активити, а другое. Каким образом это можно реализовать правильно?

На ум приходит только перенаправление при загрузке с первого активити на то, которое нужно, через `intent`, но вероятно, это костыль еще тот.

Comment: Для загрузки данных требуется активити (взаимодействие с пользователем) или они просто забираются откуда-то ?

Comment: @pavlofff через asynctask забираются с сервера. От пользователя требуется нажать кнопку в первом активити, его перекинет на второе, где данные будут скачиваться и использоваться в дальнейшем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения вашей задачи логично использовать одну активити и два фрагмента, в зависимости от условия, которое мы проверяем в активити ([первый запуск или нет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446593/177345)), в дальнейшем отображать один из фрагментов - первый дает разрешение на получение данных, второй работает с этими данными.

Comment: Спасибо, дельный совет

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант в первой активити в методе onCreate() сделать необходимую вам проверку, и по условию тут же перейти в другую. Так как боюсь что задать где в манифесте другую активити для входа нет возможности

Comment: В данный момент так и делаю, но мне кажется, что это не совсем верно